# accessing router via telnet lib python

Tags: python, telnetlib

I'm working on a code that uses telnetlib of python to connect to a router and execute commands and stores the output in a file.

I'm using read_until('#') function and expecting a Router prompt, then execute the next command but my code freezes when I receive a '--More--' data from the remote telnet side. I tried using a pattern match to find '--More--' but then sometime the --More-- keyword doesn't come at once.

Any suggestion ?

Do I have to send some IAC command to the remote telnet side ?

Answer (score 0):

> sometime the --More-- keyword doesn't come at once

Try passing in a timeout.

Example: set timeout to 5 seconds for  [read_until()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.read_until):

```
read_until('--More--', 5)
```

Alternatively, you could use the [expect()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.expect) function to look for either '#' or '--More--' with a timeout:

```
expect(['#', '--More--'], 5)
```

Comment: I have done both of them, but they don't work. It doesn't detect the word at all. It just freezes there.

Comment: Are you sure '--More--' is there? Try using read_very_eager() in place of read_until( '--More--') to see that it's there.

Comment: I enabled the debug mode and I saw the word ... It is there

Comment: Could you paste your code here so we can look at what's going on?